# Spring schedulers didnt work properly

Tags: java, spring

There is Spring project deploed on Weblogic 12.
In project there are few spring schedulers like

```
@Component
public class ExampleScheduler {

    @Autowired
    ExampleService exampleService;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    private void run(){
        exampleService.doSomething();
    }    
}
```

Settings for schedulers:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="20"/>
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="40"/>
```

And @EnableScheduling in class with @Configuration.

The problem is that fixedDelay works correctly two times and then pause between iterations becomes like 1.5 minutes.
I've tried fixedRate or cron in Scheduled annotation, but it didn't help.

Method in scheduled task works like 100ms, project have enough memory, but schedulers works slow.

Comment: You either use XML with `<task:scheduler />` or `@EnableScheduling` you shouldn't have both. Also you are on WebLogic so you probably should be using a managed thread pool instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 0):

fixedDelay argument is designed so that the timer for the next task starts after the previous finishes. i.e. If your task took .5 seconds to run then it'll effectively repeat ev0ery 1.5 seconds.

> p.s. so fixedDelay would be best to avoid multiple processes from trying to beat each other and causing a race condition. For example, you have a scheduled task to update some values, and this process can take anywhere from .1 sec to 5 sec but you want to refresh every second. You'll use fixedDelay to avoid having multiple threads trying to complete the same task at the same time where the task that is using old data finishes last thus could erase the correct values from the newer tasks.

fixedRate measures from the start of each process. And would be this straight forward:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=500)
```

Because you need it every half-second, cron wouldn't be the optimal choice because it can only specify to the second, but if you needed to it would look like this, with 6 input spots and zone being optional:

```
@Scheduled(zone = "EST", cron = "* * * * * *")
```

[For the spring document link.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

Answer (score 0):

your class must have at least these annotations :

package org.springframework.scheduling.annotation

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
```

you can set it with a fixedDelay

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
```

with initialDelay also:

```
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 1000)
```

or with a fixedRate (when each execution of the task is independent)

```
   @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the scheduler component is not properly scanned by the @ComponentScan annotation.